# TCP connection with multiple proxies in between

Tags: networking, proxy, tcp

Client sends an `Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive` header, the intermediate smart proxy sees this header and replaces it with `Connection: Keep-Alive` and sends to the web-server. All good and fine.

What if there are 2 smart proxies in between. When the first one forwards `Connection: Keep-Alive` to the second, the second doesn't know what to with this header. It knows what to do with `Proxy-Connection`, but not `Connection: Keep-Alive`. Does it just resend the header to the web server? Wouldn't that cause problems in current TCP connection?

Comment: I don't know about it, you could check with wireshark (a packet sniffer).. Can a proxy send to a proxy?  bear in mind that the protocol for communication with an http proxy is different to the protocol for connecting to an http server. e.g. `GET http://blah.com/abc HTTP/1.0`  vs `GET /abc HTTP/1.0`  So one has http one doesn't so the protocol differs. So maybe when sending to an http proxy vs sending to a web server, it changes it accordingly.  i.e. maybe a proxy seeing it is connecting to a proxy, will use `Proxy-Connection Keep-Alive`

Comment: You can run wireshark on every machine with a proxy, and see what comes in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Client sends an Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive header, the intermediate smart proxy sees this header and replaces it with Connection: Keep-Alive and sends to the web-server.

That's not how it works.

`Proxy-Connection` and `Connection` are hop-by-hop headers and not end-to-end headers. This means the client decides that it wants to use a persistent connection with the proxy and the proxy decides it wants to have a persistent connection with the upstream host (server or proxy). It is not that the proxy wants to have a persistent connection just because the client wants it but these are independent decisions. In fact a client might use the same TCP connection to the proxy for accessing multiple hosts while the proxy needs to make different TCP connections out of it because it needs to access different hosts.

Apart from that `Proxy-Connection` is wrong anyway and should be `Connection` only, no matter if the next hop is a proxy or the target server. See also https://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/158.

> Wouldn't that cause problems in current TCP connection?

These headers are just meant as a wish and keep-alive is implicit with HTTP/1.1 anyway, i.e. the header is no needed in this case at all when the client wants to have keep-alive.  And since this is a wish only both client and server may close the underlying TCP connection at any time between requests. There might be situations where the server closes the connection at exact the same time as the client is sending a new request and the client has to deal with this situation, in most cases by redoing the request within a new TCP connection.